# XCode as a debugger, tutorial?

Tags: xcode, macos

I've never used debuggers, except for occasionally GDB's backtrace to find a segfault.  I'm currently working with a moderate sized C hydrodynamics code, where I think it might be time to start using a nice GUI debugger instead of sticking `fprintf` statements everywhere.

Can anyone point me towards a good getting started tutorial on using XCode (10.7) as a debugger for a C project?

Answer (score 2):

Is the code already setup as an XCode project? If yes, this question has already been answered: [Where is there a good tutorial on how to use Xcode's debugger properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365267/where-is-there-a-good-tutorial-on-how-to-use-xcodes-debugger-properly) Admitted, most links are dead by now. But [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=xcode+debugging+tutorial) comes up with a lot of useful links, even video.

Comment: No, its not setup in xcode at all.  Is that a difficult step in-and-of-itself?

Comment: It is not difficult. Just an additional step. Xcode even supports building of Makefile-based projects: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/preparing/preparing.html